# what is wrong with my script, export psd to bmp?

Tags: python, export, photoshop, bmp

I am trying to export my psd file to bmp.

If I del zhe line ###here, it generator test.png correctly, 
but i want to get bmp file,

if I use   ###here , I get  "AttributeError: Property 'Photoshop.BMPSaveOptions.Format' can not be set."

```
import win32com.client
import os

fn='test.psd'
psApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Photoshop.Application')
options = win32com.client.Dispatch('Photoshop.ExportOptionsSaveForWeb')
options.Format = 13         # PNG
options.PNG8 = False        # Sets it to PNG-24 bit
#options = win32com.client.Dispatch('Photoshop.BMPSaveOptions') ###here del
#options.Format = 2         # bmp
#
fd=os.path.abspath('.')
fk=os.path.join(fd, fn)
doc = psApp.Open(fk)
fn='BBB'
fn = os.path.splitext(fk)[0] + '_' + fn + '.png'
#fn = os.path.splitext(fk)[0] + '_' + fn + '.bmp'  ###
doc.Export(ExportIn=fn, ExportAs=2,  Options=options) #ExportAs=2,
doc.Close(2)
```

Comment: Please take this [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before asking a question. It'll make your questions more efficient.

Comment: You're passing `Options=self.options`, but only define a local variable with the `options = win32com.client.Dispatch('Photoshop.BMPSaveOptions')` statement.

Comment: yes,  i modify it now.  thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am reading your question properly (apoligies if I am not) you want to save the file in BMP and not PNG format. My guess is you need to change the options.Format

`options.Format = 13         # PNG`

After some research it looks like BMP is *2* so I'd change your code to:

`options.Format = 2 # BMP`

As a note, I'd also recommend you change your filename when you save your file to avoid confusion. Maybe this?

`fn = os.path.splitext(fk)[0] + '_' + fn + '.bmp'`

Comment: thank you,  if  i modify it:   options.Format = 2 # BMP ,      AttributeError: Property 'Photoshop.BMPSaveOptions.Format' can not be set.

Comment: I may have only been half right. Try this.

Instead of this -

`options = win32com.client.Dispatch('Photoshop.ExportOptionsSaveForWeb')`
`options.Format = 13         # PNG`
`options.PNG8 = False        # Sets it to PNG-24 bit`

Try this:
`options = win32.Dispatch("Photoshop.BMPSaveOptions")`  

`options.Format = 2`

Comment: I solved it by reference : http://www.joshwright.com/tips/automating-photoshop-with-c- ,  use doc.SaveAs(fn, options, True), ok ! hehe